# Is it possible to set device's Latitude and Longitude using ADB SHELL?

Tags: adb, geolocation, shell

I know how to set locatlon for emulators using device configuration interface from Motodoev Studio for example. But, how I can set locatlon for a device?

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively what might also be an option here is to use Appium's [io.appium.setting's app](https://github.com/appium/io.appium.settings).

Once that app's installed on the device you can give it permissions and mock location through adb like this:

```
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
  adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

  adb shell am start -W -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000
  adb shell appops set io.appium.settings android:mock_location allow

  adb shell am startservice -e longitude 28 -e latitude 77 io.appium.settings/.LocationService;
```

For more info on the app and some other intents check out [their readme](https://github.com/appium/io.appium.settings#changing-of-system-settings)

Answer (score 5):

this is possible using ADB shell:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix -82.411629 28.054553
OK
```

Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587369/950427

Comment: isn't this for a device? AFAIK, there is no way to set the location other than mock the location on your device, and add a test location provider.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what he was looking for. What is your question?

Comment: Down vote because OP is explicitly asking about on a Device. This only works for the Emulator.

Comment: @cde I answered this question 3.5+ years ago. It helped OP at the time.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative to @jmp answer, I can recommend to use instead of Appium's app the [FakeTraveler](https://github.com/mcastillof/FakeTraveler) It has not the disadvantage to run a lot of `adb` permission commands, which not really work out of the box and without search google why setting permission ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION don't work.

[FakeTraveler](https://github.com/mcastillof/FakeTraveler) guides you automatic to right developer setting ♥

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, there are many mock location apps out there, but those don't really answer the question of changing the location using ADB. Does this app allow controlling the location using ADB?