# How can i set location manually with adb?

Tags: adb, geolocation, location-services

i dont know how to set location over shell with commands, for my test i use "bluestacks 5", i got an native app for setting location manually with mouse click but i need to set it with shell this is my logs and i connot found how to make that :

gps coordinates are anonymized

Native bluestack APP for setting location : com.location.provider

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
9
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
28
```

returned logs with logcat, when i click on the maps for setting new gps location with my mouse

```
    12-23 11:32:19.446  1956  2327 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_LOCATION, 1, Location[gps 48,384367,7,774755 hAcc=1 et=?!? alt=0.0 vel=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???])
12-23 11:32:19.447  1956  1970 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_LOCATION, 1, Location[gps 48,384367,7,774755 hAcc=1 et=+6m52s385ms alt=0.0 vel=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[{satellites=8, maxCn0=65, meanCn0=49}]}])
12-23 11:32:19.447  1956  2327 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@1db68ac)
12-23 11:32:19.448  1956  1970 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@1db68ac)
12-23 11:32:19.471  3490  3890 I Counters: exceeded sample count in FrameTime
12-23 11:32:20.448  1956  2327 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_LOCATION, 1, Location[gps 48,384367,7,774755 hAcc=1 et=?!? alt=0.0 vel=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=???])
12-23 11:32:20.449  1956  1970 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_LOCATION, 1, Location[gps 48,384367,7,774755 hAcc=1 et=+6m53s388ms alt=0.0 vel=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[{satellites=8, maxCn0=77, meanCn0=44}]}])
12-23 11:32:20.450  1956  2327 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@5582975)
12-23 11:32:20.451  1956  1970 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@5582975)
12-23 11:32:20.480  3490  3890 I Counters: exceeded sample count in FrameTime
12-23 11:32:21.150  1956  1971 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
12-23 11:32:21.150  1956  1971 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.MODE_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
12-23 11:32:21.154  2396  2396 D BstCommandProcessor-Service: onStartCommand called
12-23 11:32:21.154  2396  2396 D BstCommandProcessor-Service: Saving new location: 32.121232346,9.7914821548497375
12-23 11:32:21.155  2531  5077 I NearbyDiscovery: FastPairHandler: Received action android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
12-23 11:32:21.158  1956  1971 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
12-23 11:32:21.158  1956  1971 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.MODE_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
12-23 11:32:21.158  2396  2396 D BstCommandProcessor-Service: saveLocationDataToSharedPrefs : 32.121232346,9.7914821548497375
12-23 11:32:21.163  2531  5077 D BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): OFF
12-23 11:32:21.166  2531  5077 I NearbyDiscovery: FastPairScanner2: eventType=LOCATION, intReq=false, scanning=false, scanAllowed=true, bleEnabled=false, bleScanAvailable=false, lockScanRate=false [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to set device's Latitude and Longitude using ADB SHELL?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35716/44325)

Comment: its a specific problem with bluestacks 5